# Has Alphonse Pyramus de Candolle's "Géographie botanique raisonnée" ever been translated into German or English?

Tags: reference-request, biology

Alphones Pyramus de Candolle (1806-1893), the son of Augustin-Pyrame de Candolle (1778-1841), has been an important figure (as was his father) in the development of plant geography.

The younger Candolle's work "Géographie botanique raisonnée" (1856) has been an especially  important text for the history of plant geography since it combines botanical arithmetic with hypothesis driven scientific research. The scholar Janet Browne call this text "the cornerstone of mid-century ideas on the subject".[^1]

I was wondering if this text (or any of his <s>for example his "Essai élémentaire de Géographie botanique" from 1820</s>) has been translated in either German or English as these two languages were the other principal languages of biological distribution studies. It would also help myself, since my French is regrettably limited.

[^1]: [Browne, J. 2001. History of Biogeography. eLS](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1038/npg.els.0003092/full), p. 2

EDIT: As noted in my answer the Essai élémentaire de Géographie botanique was written by Auguste de Candolle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research has shown, that there exists a list of de Candolle's publications from 1824 until May 1883:

> Liste complète des ouvrages et opuscules publiés par M. Alph. de Candolle dans le laps des soixante années de 1824 à mai 1883.

[It's available on Hathi Trust.](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/009173065).

On top of that, and even more comprehensive, is Frans Stafleu's Taxonomic Literature. Here's is [Volume 1](http://biodiversitylibrary.org/page/33120564) and here's the [supplementary Volume III](http://biodiversitylibrary.org/page/33266663) on Alphonse de Candolle.

**Both do not list any translation of "Géographie botanique raisonnée".**

P.S.: I also realized, that the "Essai élémentaire de Géographie botanique" from 1820 was actually written by Auguste de Candolle (the father) and not by Alphonse. I have edited my question as regards to this.

Answer (score 3):

Origin of cultivated plants / by Alphonse de Candolle.

```
Main author:Candolle, Alphonse de, 1806-1893.
Title:Origin of cultivated plants / by Alphonse de Candolle.
Other Entries:Darwin, Francis, Sir, 1848-1925, former owner.
University of Cambridge. Department of Plant Sciences, former owner.
Published:London : Kegan Paul, Trench & co, 1884.
Description:viii p., 1 l., 468 p ; 20 cm.
Series statement:International scientific series ; vol. xlix
Notes:Original French edition, 1883; first American edition, 1885.
```

[From the Cambridge University Library catalogue]

Answer (score 0):

I have translated the text but not the tables. My translation is very rough and the parts I've cleaned up are much better but the work is endless. I've translated many of his scientific articles and am working on Alph's edition of his father's Memories et souvenirs, another long project. I've also transcribed and translated all of letters to Asa Gray (~75).